# How to have an active label on screen?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

Imagine in my app I have a label representing a virtual time and I want to change this label and update the time but this time is not system time and I want to be able to change it with different speeds (like every one real second is one or two minutes in this virtual time) and I also want to be able to call some functions at specific times.

I use UIKit.

How can I do this?

Comment: I used SpriteKit before and in SpriteKit there is an update function which can handle this things but I searched and I didn't find something like that in UIKit and also I found tutorials to make timers but I can't do things I said that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will find that UIKit has [`UILabel`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/index.html).  `UILabel` is a pretty straightforward thing to use.  You can create it programmatically and position it, or use Interface Builder to create it as part of your View Controller's layout.

Either way, to update it, simply set the [`text`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILabel/text) property.

You can use [`NSTimer`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/index.html) to update the text with a time and scale it using some sort of multiplier.  Time calculations get tricky, so you may need to open a different question with more specifics about your time update.

Use the [`scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSTimer/scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:) method to have it call a method on your object, then `[NSTimer invalidate];` to cancel it.